# How can I programmatically test for cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

How can I check/detect if the user is accepting cookies or not? Using ASP.NET (C#)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28VS.71%29.aspx#vbtchaspnetcookies101anchor10)

> One way to determine whether cookies are accepted is by trying to write a cookie and then trying to read it back again. If you can't read the cookie you wrote, you assume that cookies are turned off in the browser.

write :

```
Sub Page_Load()
   If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      If Request.QueryString("AcceptsCookies") Is Nothing Then
           Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Value = "ok"
           Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Expires = _
              DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
           Response.Redirect("TestForCookies.aspx?redirect=" & _
              Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString))
      Else
           labelAcceptsCookies.Text = "Accept cookies = " & _
              Request.QueryString("AcceptsCookies")
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

then read

```
Sub Page_Load()
    Dim redirect As String = Request.QueryString("redirect")
    Dim acceptsCookies As String
    ' Was the cookie accepted?
    If Request.Cookies("TestCookie") Is Nothing Then
        ' No cookie, so it must not have been accepted
        acceptsCookies = 0
    Else
        acceptsCookies = 1
        ' Delete test cookie
        Response.Cookies("TestCookie").Expires = _
           DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
    End If
    Response.Redirect(redirect & "?AcceptsCookies=" & acceptsCookies, _
       True)
End Sub
```

Comment: Should the data transfer stall for some reason (network load) by more than a minute, it will not function. Maybe put a longer time.

Comment: make a check to make sure people wont use your redirect page for bad thing, like redirecting to fishing website etc...

Comment: seems like its impossible. I was trying to prevent writing to session and cookie if i know cookie works. I guess i need to write both.

Answer (score 1):

Save a value to the cookies, make a redirect to some page and try to read the value back. If it works, cookies are enabled. If not, then not.

Answer (score 0):

1. create one
2. try to read it?